# switching from GET to POST ajax with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, security, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter in [ajax pager mode](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html). I need to protect my JSON data, so how do I switch from  GET to POST. any other ways to protect data from accessed through url in the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random value and store that random value in a session variable. Include the randow value with the ajax request.

If the random value is missing or if it is not equal to the session variable deny access to the json data.

In the PHP page which contains json data, paste this code at the beginning.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_REQUEST['randomVal']) || ($_REQUEST['randomVal'] != $_SESSION['randomVal'])) {
    echo "Direct Access to the page denied";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It's easy to cheat on this, working woith GET can be trivially altered with DOM manipulation to forge requests and cookies/sessions.

Comment: You are using AJAX right? Change the random token on each request i.e. in the PHP page . It makes the things difficult for an attacker.We can also encode the java script.

http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html

Comment: I did the session the token the HTTP_REFERER, but in order to close the big hole U have to switch from GET to POST on tablesorter ajax calls.

Comment: As you are using javascript GET/POST doesn't matter, anyone can view the script and find how the request is been send.

Comment: Vishnu we all know that and that's why we like to do something to prevent from viewing the data itself.

Comment: Try to encode the java script. check this out http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html 
If possible create your own algorithm for encoding java script.